# How do you get AngularJS to bind to the title attribute of an A tag?

Tags: angularjs

The intent is to have a product name appear in the tooltip of a thumbnail. 
Browsers do not create a tooltip from "ng-title" or "ng-attr-title."

We are using AngularJS version 1.0.7. 
You can prepend any attribute with "ng-" or "ng-attr" and Angular will bind accordingly. However, it doesn't seem to "bind" to the title attirbute of the HTML "A" tag.

**Ex. 1.**

Code: `<a title="{{product.shortDesc}}" ...>`

Expected result: `<a title="Canon Powershot XS50 12MB Digital Camera" ...>`

Actual result: `<a title="{{product.shortDesc}}" ...>` We get undesired braces in the tooltip.

**Ex. 2.**

Code: `<a ng-attr-title="{{product.shortDesc}}" ...>`

Expected result: `<a title="Canon Powershot XS50 12MB Digital Camera" ...>`

Actual result: `<a ng-attr-title="Canon Powershot XS50 12MB Digital Camera" ...>`

We do not get a plain `title` attirbute, nor do we get a working tooltip.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

It looks like `ng-attr` is a new directive in [AngularJS 1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cf17c6af475eace31cf52944afd8e10d3afcf6c0) that you can possibly use in this case.

```
<!-- example -->
<a ng-attr-title="{{product.shortDesc}}"></a>
```

However, if you stay with 1.0.7, you can probably write a custom directive to mirror the effect.

Answer (score 54):

Sometimes it is not desirable to use interpolation on title attribute or on any other attributes as for that matter, because
they get parsed before the interpolation takes place. So:

```
<!-- dont do this -->
<!-- <a title="{{product.shortDesc}}" ...> -->
```

If an attribute with a binding is prefixed with the ngAttr prefix (denormalized as ng-attr-) then during the binding will be applied to the corresponding unprefixed attribute. This allows you to bind to attributes that would otherwise be eagerly processed by browsers. The attribute will be set only when the binding is done. The prefix is then removed:

```
<!-- do this -->
<a ng-attr-title="{{product.shortDesc}}" ...>
```

(Ensure that you are not using a very earlier version of Angular). Here's a demo fiddle using v1.2.2:

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzHe3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is your version of AngularJS; `ng-attr` is not working due to the fact that it was introduced in version 1.1.4. I am unsure as to why `title="{{product.shortDesc}}"` isn't working for you, but I imagine it is for similar reasons (old Angular version). I tested this on 1.2.9 and it is working for me.

As for the other answers here, this is NOT among the few use cases for `ng-attr`! This is a simple double-curly-bracket situation:

```
<a title="{{product.shortDesc}}" ng-bind="product.shortDesc" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the fiddle here for a quick answer

```
data-ng-attr-title="{{d.age > 5 ? 'My age is greater than threshold': ''}}"
```

[Displays Title over elements conditionally using Angular JS](https://jsfiddle.net/Y2KPRABU/n9L1xvwn/2/)

Answer (score -4):

The search `query` model lives in the scope defined by the `ng-controller="whatever"` directive. So if you want to bind the query model to `<title>`, you have to move the `ngController` declaration to an HTML element that is a common parent to both the body and title elements:

`<html ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">`

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03