# How can i conditionally apply title in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I conditionally apply title in angular.js

```
<span title=" Create " class="check-{{ item.status }}"></span>
```

If status equals to true, then I want to show title as *Create* else *Delete*.

For class I can apply conditions like

```
ng-class="{true: 'active'}[isActive]
```

and in controller

```
$scope.isActive = true;
```

or

```
$scope.isActive = false;
```

How can I do the same in title?

I tried something like:

```
title = " item.status = true | 'create' "
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just do this

```
<span title="{{ item.status ? 'create' : 'delete'}}" class="check-{{ item.status }}"></span>
```

Comment: It's important to point out that even though you can write JS code inside {{ }}, it won't work if you do item.status ? "create" : "delete" as it conflicts with title="

Answer (score 4):

To avoid directly binding to HTML Element properties, you can use the following:

```
<span [attr.title]="item.status ? 'create' : 'delete'" [ngClass]="'check-' +  item.status"></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

To anyone still trying to figure this out:

Use `ng-attr-title="{{ item.status ? 'create' : 'delete'}}"`. (Introduced in Angular 1.1.4)

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230868/how-do-you-get-angularjs-to-bind-to-the-title-attribute-of-an-a-tag) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I wanted to have my solution more dynamic. This is what I came up with:

```
directives.directive('myStatus', function() {

var getStatusClass = function (currentStatus) {
    switch (currentStatus) {
        case 'U':
            //a defined css class
            return "unassigned-background";
        ...
        default :
            return "error";
    }
};

var getStatusTitle = function (currentStatus) {
    switch (currentStatus) {
        case 'U':
            //some string you want to use
            return "Unassigned. Inactive";
        ...
        default :
            return "error";
    }
};

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span>{{status}}</span>',
    scope: {
        status: '@status' //<-- take note that this is a one-way binding!
    },
    link : function (scope, element, attributes) {
        element.addClass(getTerminalStatusClass(scope.status));
        element.attr("title", getTerminalStatusTitle(scope.status));

    }
}});
```

Then you can use this like:

```
<my-status status={{myScopeVariable}}></my-status>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with latest versions of angular then you can achieve it like this

```
<span [title]="item.status ? 'create' : 'delete'" [ngClass]="'check-' +  item.status"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title="{{ type.enabled ? ('Enabled  '+type.name) : ('Disabled '+ type.name+) }}"
```

This might help you.