# How to show a tab title in angular 2 only if I have more than one tab

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs

Using **angular 2**, I am using the `<tabs>` element. I iterate over some conditions to show them as different tabs. The code looks like this:

```
<tabs>
    <tab *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index" [title]="'message.productDetail.'+(index>0?'end':'start')">
    ...
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

I would like to add a condition to show the `[title]` only if `items.length > 1`. I would like to avoid showing tabs with only one tab.

I have tried putting a conditional text [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036997/3294286), but it still shows the tab (without text). I want the tab to hide.

For example, I want to show "Tab 1", and "Tab 2" if I have more than one tab. But I would like to see the tabs like a panel if I were to have only "Tab 1" or "Tab 2".

I want to show the content of the tab, I just don't want to have the "tab selector" because it is unnecessary and takes a lot of space. I would like it to behave like a panel.

The way I made it work is not very nice because I do some **copy and paste** code. Like this:

```
<tabs *ngIf="items.length > 1">
    <tab *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index" [title]="'message.productDetail.'+(index>0?'end':'start')">
    ... Content using item variable
    </tab>
</tabs>

<div *ngIf="items.length == 1">
    ... Same content as before using a hardcoded items[0] variable
</tabs>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve adding `[title]` on each tab? It would be great if you can express the output you want.

Comment: I would like the tabs to behave like a panel if I were to have just one tab

Comment: @sebadagostino , do you have any working demo , where we can see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2869

You can do something like

```
<tabs>
<tab *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index"   
[attr.title]="items.length > 1 ? 'message.productDetail.'+(index>0?'end':'start') : undefined">
...
</tab>
```

Comment: I tried this. This is pretty much the same as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036829/how-can-i-conditionally-apply-title-in-angular-js/24036997#24036997
I probably would have to use ngTemplate and divs instead of tabs