# HTML Modal Title attribute AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to dynamically set the Title of a 'modal' view using AngularJS (the title should change with respect to some selected user). The HTML is of the form

```
<modal  title="modalRolesTableTitle" visible="showModalRolesTable"> SOME CONTENT</modal>
```

In my AngularJS file I have declared both scope variables

```
$scope.showModalRightsTable = false;

$scope.modalRolesTableTitle = null;
```

and the *visible* attribute works fine. The *modalRightsTableTitle* variable is being assigned correctly (firebug).

I was hoping someone could explain functionality wise why the *visible* attribute binds and the *title* does not and perhaps provide a solution.

Also I have tried *ng-attr-title="modalRolesTableTitle"* without success (It just displays the text *'modalRolesTableTitle'* ).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, this was the first thing I tired and it did not work. Furthermore as I mentioned previously the visible attribute was bound without the need for curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Always use expression for binding.

```
<modal  title="{{modalRolesTableTitle}}" visible="{{showModalRightsTable}}"> SOME CONTENT</modal>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/601/)

If you are using AngularJS 1.1.4 and above then you can use ng-attr-title

See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230868/how-do-you-get-angularjs-to-bind-to-the-title-attribute-of-an-a-tag)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, this was the first thing I tired and it did not work. Furthermore as I mentioned previously the visible attribute was bound without the need for curly braces.

Comment: Okay.does title attribute work now or still facing issue?

Comment: Not yet. I have tried every possible permutation of "{{modalRolesTableTitle}}", "modalRolesTableTitle" and {{modalRolesTableTitle}}.

Also (interesting note) when I try the format 

<modal visible="{{showModalRolesTable}}">

the visible attribute does not bind

Comment: See my edited answer. Meanwhile can you pls share a fiddle showing the said error?

Answer (score 0):

It's very work around but maybe this solution can be appropriate for you:

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#myModal' ) );
myEl.attr('title',"My tooltip");
```

of course you have to set:

```
<modal id="myModal"  title="" visible="{{showModalRightsTable}}"> SOME CONTENT</modal>
```