# AngularJs SPA and linking from social media

Tags: angularjs, facebook, dom, twitter, angular-ui-router

So I made this SPA blog using AngularJs and parse.com, and it works nicely:
http://brianemilius.com

But when I link to posts in my blog from, say Facebook or Twitter, the cards in my (facebook or twitter) posts show the title as `{{ template.siteName }}` instead of the actual title.

[image]

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: The crawlers don't execute JavaScript, which is why you're seeing the angular expressions.Look into using a service like: https://prerender.io/ in order to fix this issue.

Comment: prerender.io actually looks really good! I'm gonna give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if not already you might want to take a look at ng-cloak
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Nope, this does not do anything of what I need. :/ Thanks though

Comment: @BrianEmilius take a look at this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230868/how-do-you-get-angularjs-to-bind-to-the-title-attribute-of-an-a-tag

Comment: Ah, but my problem isn't with an attribute but with the <title/> tag in my head section.