# how can call the scope function on ng-title attribute in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, attributes

This is my html code

```
 <td ng-title="tileOfAbsent(this.attendance.absent)" ng-  
  style="IsAbsOrPres(this.attendance.absent)" style="color: red">  
  {{attendance.absent}}</td>
```

This is controller

```
 $scope.tileOfAbsent = function (value) {
            var title1= "Absent";
            var title2= "Present";
            if (value == "AA") {
                return title1;
            }
            else {
                return title2;
            }
        }

 $scope.IsAbsOrPres = function (value) {
        var style1 = { color: "#F41212" };
        var style2 = { color: "#178908" };
        if (value == "AA") {
            return style1;
        }
        else {
            return style2;
        }
    }
```

Problem is `tileOfAbsent` function does not executed(I have checked with using break point). But the `IsAbsOrPres` function is executed as expected .

> Why `ng-title` does not call the function?

Comment: what is `ng-title` directive can you show us the doc? is it angular builtin directive?

Comment: what is source of `ngTitle` directive? Did you try just using `title`? Can't arbitrarily prefix `ng-` to attributes and expect anything to happen

Comment: `It looks like ng-attr is a new directive in AngularJS 1.1.4 that you can possibly use in this case.`

 See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18346925/2218635:

Comment: You are using `ng-title`, not `ng-attr-title`. So one more time: do you understand well that there is no ngTitle directive shipped with Angular? If you use it make sure to include source code for in in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it by using `title` instead of `ng-title`

like, `title="{{tileOfAbsent(this.attendance.absent)}}"`

---

this is my full working code

```
<td title="{{tileOfAbsent(this.attendance.absent)}}" ng-style="IsAbsOrPres
(this.attendance.absent)" style="color: red">{{attendance.absent}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ng-attr-title** instead of ng-title. In this case is mandatory write the method between double curly braces like **"{{ ... }}"**.

```html
    ng-attr-title="{{ tileOfAbsent(this.attendance.absent) }}"
```