# How can I make a button title equal to a value on my scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a button inside of an ng-repeat div on my template, and I would like to set it's title property to be equal to a value from my scope, but it is showing up as the string, not the value.

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="step in steps">
  <button title="step.description">Text</button>
</div>
```

On hover, the above displays the literal string "step.description" instead of the value from my scope. Currently my controller has an array on it called steps, and each of the step objects in that array has a key named "description" set to a different string.

Comment: `ng-attr-title="{{step.description}}"`

Comment: so you want to see the description on the hover right?

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked yes, that is correct. `<button ng-attr-title=">{{step.description}}">` works, AND `<button title="{{step.description}}">` works. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this link can help you.  [How do you get AngularJS to bind to the title attribute of an A tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230868/how-do-you-get-angularjs-to-bind-to-the-title-attribute-of-an-a-tag)

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <div ng-repeat="step in steps">
          <button ng-attr-title="{{step.description}}">Text</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
```

You can use `ng-attr-title` to bind value on hover.`ng-attr` is a new directive in AngularJS 1.1.4

```
 app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.steps = [
          {
          description: 'Test1'
        },
         {
          description: 'Test2'
        },
         {
          description : 'Test3'
        }

        ];
```

Here is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ql4GHSkcuD1r9SywL2mi?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! That seems like a very useful directive, thank you for the heads up. Curiously, `<button title="{{step.description}}">` also gave me the desired effect. Any idea why?

Comment: @devigner both `ng-attr-title` or `title` can  bind data in `angularJs`.

Comment: Right, I just get confused, when am I supposed to use `{{...}}` and when do I just use a regular string?