# Angular js binding on title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, binding

I need help in trying to bind the following variable to an HTML attribute using Angular JS. In my controller file I have this

controller.js

```
$scope.errorDialog = function(errorTitle, errorMessage){
      $scope.errorTitle = errorTitle;
      $scope.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
}
```

errorTitle and errorMessage parameters are both set in another function.

In my html file i have this error message box (using Jquery UI)

abc.html

```
<div title="{{errorTitle}}" id="dialog-confirm" >
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>{{errorMessage}}</p>
</div>
```

For some reason the title is not displayed. I've tried changing it to 
ng-attr-title="{{errorTitle}}" but that doesn't work either. I've also tried to use a function in the title attribute and to return the value of errorTitle but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get AngularJS to bind to the title attribute of an A tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230868/how-do-you-get-angularjs-to-bind-to-the-title-attribute-of-an-a-tag)

Comment: Can you show some more code? specially the way you've implemented jQuery UI message box.

Comment: @Canastro i went through that post before making this. I already tried ng-attr-title but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible issues here:

1. Are you sure you are sharing the $scope of your controller with the dialog?

If the div creating your dialog is not accessible by your controller, which means it's not a DOM node in the subtree of children of your controller root element, it will not display the properties (and will give no errors)

2. Where are you calling $scope.errorDialog?

If you are running that call outside of a $digest loop, you can maybe solve this by calling `$scope.$apply` after setting the properties. This wouldn't be the best solution though, it would be better to wrap the call of this function in the following fashion

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.errorDialog('title', 'message');
})
```

This would allow AngularJS to eventually intercept errors happened while executing `$scope.errorDialog`

Comment: $scope.errorDialog is called from another function in the controller.js file. The errorDialog function is called properly since the errorMessage data is displayed. But i cannot dynamically set the title attribute using AngularJs on the index.html file

Comment: What I really want to do is to display the title attribute dynamically in the errorDialog box